# Custom command palette in VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension that adds a status bar item. I want that when clicked, it will open a custom command palette with special commands. The functionality I am looking for is very similar to the built in Git item on the left of the status bar, which when clicked open a palette that offer to do Git stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in Git item uses the QuickPick Capability.

Check out the API [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPick), and a demo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/quickinput-sample).